# AS3 Displaying data between frames

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I have a Android Air project written in AS3, when the project starts I am loading the music and loading the XML file to be parsed.  In the first frame I call my classes to parse the XML and set the nodes at strings, and to play the audio, these both work fine.  Also in my first frame I am declaring some textfields to input the data from the XML file so that when the user enters frame 3 the user is able to see this data from the XML file.  This also works fine.  The problem I am having is going between frame 4 and back to frame 3, the data in the textfields disapears?  I trace the strings from the XML class that are holding the data and these values appear everytime, but going from frame 3 to frame 4 and back to frame 3 wipes out the textfield display? Can anyone point me in the right direction?
thanks
Scientific

Ok here is some code from frame one where I am declaring the textfields

```
    var name1TextField:TextField = new TextField();
    var name2TextField:TextField = new TextField();

    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.font = "_sans";
    format.color = 0xF8FBF8;
    format.size = 36;

    //set the names format to the textfields
    name1TextField.defaultTextFormat = format;
    name2TextField.defaultTextFormat = format;

    highScore1.addChild(name1TextField);
    highScore2.addChild(name2TextField);
```

Here is the code calling the XML parsing class and setting the text to the nodes

```
    var network:networkScores = new networkScores();
    addChild(network);

    var timer4:Timer = new Timer(600);
    timer4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, scoresDis);
    timer4.start();

    function scoresDis(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
       name1TextField.text = network.name1;
       name2TextField.text = network.name2;
       //trace(name1TextField.text);
       //trace(name2TextField.text);

       name1TextField.width = 230;
       name2TextField.width = 230;
       timer4.stop();

    }
```

Previously above I had stated that I am calling the audio class and the xml class from the first frame, declaring the text fields and moving on from there.  Now I have decided that since this XML file is a list of scores and coded be always changing, I thought it would be good to load and parse this file everytime I enter frame 3.  The same thing is still happening, I have my scores display and then when I go to frame 4 and back to frame three, the scores do not display, but when I trace the data from the class, it displays properly.
Thanks
Scientific

Comment: Can you give more details about the textfields? Are they classic textFields, TLFTextfields? Dynamic (I think obviously but you never know), etc etc.

Comment: Also, can you post the code for populating the textfields on frame 3 please? Need to see some code cause this could definitely be the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue happen before with improperly embedded fonts or something, I can't recall exactly. A quick way to test this would be to trace out the .text property of the fields too. This way, when the text isn't visible, if the .text property of the field is still populated then you know you've got a *rendering* problem.

Do this quick test and post the results, I'll update my answer with more information depending on the outcome.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for taking the time to help.  I traced the textfield.text and they displayed when I tried to come back to the frame. funny you say "embedded font," because I was unsure I did this correctly when I tried earlier.

Comment: I just removed my embedded font and tried it again with the same results